# Deployment of API Management in multiple regions, each region having just one (1) unit?

Tags: architecture, azure-api-management

I have a premier-tier API Management (APIM) instance that allows me to scale my API gateway to multiple regions. Currently, my primary region is North Europe with **just one (1) unit**, serving all my requests without any issues.

I want to make my APIM instance **highly available**, so I am thinking of adding a secondary region, say in West Europe. **Each of the two regions (primary and secondary) will have just one (1) unit for the API gateway component.**

Based on the fact that **all my users access the APIs from a single country** :

What happens if the primary region is up and running (i.e. no "region is down" issue), but for some reason (i.e. patching the APIM unit, etc.) the API gateway unit of the primary region is NOT responding?

Will APIM route requests to the secondary region, or it only works in "region is down" scenarios?

**If both regions are up and running at any time, will APIM load balance the requests it receives between the units of the two regions, or it will always use the primary region's API gateway unit?**
As I said, in my scenario, all my API users are located in the same country.

I appreciate your insights.

Answer (score 1):

APIM uses traffic manager with performance profile (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#performance) and health probes  to route traffic to its regional endpoints. When both regions are up traffic is sent to both of them according to profile logic.

If for any reason one of regional endpoints stops responding TM will stop using its IP for new DNS resolution requests.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So, even with just one (1) unit for each of my two geographic regions, I get both load-balancing benefits AND fail-over in case one of the units do not work, right?

Comment: 1 premium unit equals two nodes. Within the region they'll be randomly load balanced, i.e. each new connection has an equal chance to land on either node, so both should be equally loaded. if one goes down it's taken out of rotation. Across regions performance profile will decide. If majority of your clients close to North Europe - that region will get more load. In Azure portal you'll be able to see load by region, but nodes are hidden from end user.